# python pretty printing simple if

Tags: python, if-statement, beautifulsoup

I have pretty printed a content in this way using this code. This code prints everything out, how do I print a specific location using IF ? Such as Upper Bukit Timah, West Coast...

Area: Upper Bukit Timah
Summary: Cloudy
Latitude: 1.356084
Longitude: 103.768873

Area: West Coast
Summary: Cloudy
Latitude: 1.30039493
Longitude: 103.7504196

Area: Woodlands
Summary: Cloudy
Latitude: 1.44043052
Longitude: 103.7878418

Area: Yishun
Summary: Cloudy
Latitude: 1.42738834
Longitude: 103.8290405

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup #Using bs3


url="https://api.projectnimbus.org/neaodataservice.svc/NowcastSet"
request = urllib2.Request(url)
request.add_header("accept", "*/*")
request.add_header('AccountKey', "OSJeROQjTg4v7Ec3kiecjw==")
request.add_header('UniqueUserID', "00000000000000000000000000000001")
result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
xml_str = result.read()

soup = BeautifulStoneSoup(xml_str)

prop_list = []
for content in soup.findAll("m:properties"):
    props = {}
    for prop in content.findChildren():
        props[prop.name[2:]] = prop.text
    prop_list.append(props)


for prop in sorted(prop_list):
    print "Area: %(area)s\nSummary: %(summary)s\nLatitude: %(latitude)s\nLongitude: %(longitude)s\n" % prop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you'd have to add an `if` statement to your final `for` loop, checking whether the current entry in in some positive list. Something like this:

```
areas_to_print = ["Upper Bukit Timah", "West Coast", "Woodlands", "Yishun"]

for prop in sorted(prop_list):
    if prop["area"] in areas_to_print:
        print "Area: %(area)s\nSummary: %(summary)s\nLatitude: %(latitude)s\nLongitude: %(longitude)s\n" % prop
```

Alternatively, you could just as well add that same `if` statement to your first `for` loop, so only those entries are added to the `prop_list` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

```
for prop in sorted(prop_list):
    if (prop["area"] == "whatever u wnt or someother condition"):
        print "Area: %(area)s\nSummary: %(summary)s\nLatitude: %(latitude)s\nLongitude: %(longitude)s\n" % prop
```